# Is it ok to post gists instead of copying the code?

Tags: discussion

I'm just wondering if it's ok to post a gist link instead of copying the code in the message body (in case of medium/long scripts)

Comment: Yes its 100% legit.

Comment: I disagree, there should be enough code in the question for it to stand on its own.

Comment: Just replace jsbin/jsfiddle with gist in [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180114/when-to-use-jsbin-or-jsfiddle). To be clear: **NO, that is not OK**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, it's not. Posts on Stack Overflow need to be self-contained. To be able to answer a question or understand an answer, users should not need to leave the site. Posting your code anywhere else than on Stack Overflow, besides the obvious dangers of link rot, does violate that simple principle.

If your code is so long that it does not fit on Stack Overflow, your question might simply not be good enough. You would need to narrow your problem down until you can ask a well-illustrated and targeted question.

Comment: And as a bonus, the mere act of trying to reduce your problem to a minimal example will often lead you to solve it for yourself, and then everyone wins.