# Is it OK to post screenshots with error messages instead of copying the message?

Tags: discussion

I often see people posting a screenshot (or worse: just linking instead of embedding the image) with an error message, while the actual error message is not included in the question. That makes it hard to copy-paste the message to search for the message, nor does Stack Overflow find similar questions. In many cases the screenshot doesn't add any value.

Some examples:

- *[SYMFONY 3.1 | TWIG - Markup.php (throwing error since migrating from 2.9.X)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41922295/symfony-3-1-twig-markup-php-throwing-error-since-migrating-from-2-9-x/)*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42306013/avd-error-in-android-studio*

Based on *[Is it ok to post gists instead of copying the code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252693/is-it-ok-to-post-gists-instead-of-copying-the-code)* I think it's not OK ("Posts on Stack Overflow need to be self-contained"), but I'd like your opinion about this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, that is not okay.

> That makes it hard to copy-paste the message to search for the message, nor does Stack Overflow find similar questions.

That's exactly why we should not and do not want screenshots, Stack Overflow is not a support site; it's a Q&A-site. We collect questions and answers to **serve as resource** for people who are facing problems while programming. Making it nearly impossible to find the question & the answers goes directly against that. Another problem is that images may not be available in the future, but, as we're using Imgur, that's unlikely to happen.

If I stumble upon one of those questions **I either comment**, and ask the author to add the error message as text, **or edit it myself** (*if the rest of the question is at least decent!*).

If the author does not edit his question and doesn't react, or - worse - simply ignores it and keeps asking for an answer, I flag the question with a fitting flag reason, most likely something in the lines of "No MCVE", etc.